# Elasticsearch terms aggregation specify key list

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there anyway to specify key list to terms aggregation.

For example this is my query. I filter member field with values 72,16,92

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [{
          "or": [{
            "term": {
              "member": 72
            }
          }, {
            "term": {
              "member": 16
            }
          }, {
            "term": {
              "member": 92
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "member": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "member",
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        },
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Aggregation result returns only 16 and 72 because member=92 does not match any document.

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2360,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "member": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [{
        "key": 16,
        "doc_count": 2357
      }, {
        "key": 72,
        "doc_count": 3
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get keys in aggregation result as doc_count 0 which are not exists in resultset

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [min_doc_count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3)

```
"aggs": {
"member": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "member",
    "min_doc_count": 0,
    "order": {
      "_term": "asc"
    },
    "size": 100
  }
}
```

Comment: min_doc_count does not works for me. I dont want to get all terms. I want to specify terms that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch doesn't know about an inexistent `term` unless you specifically search for it:

```
  "aggs": {
    "member72": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "member": 72
        }
      }
    },
    "member16": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "member": 16
        }
      }
    },
    "member92": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "member": 92
        }
      }
    }
  }
```